# Is there an equivalent of Log4J for Ruby, Log4Ruby?

Tags: ruby, logging

I looked around and couldn't find one.  Is there an equivalent of Log4X for Ruby?  If not what's the best way to handle all the debug statements.  I'm fairly new to Ruby.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any idea how we can use log4j in JRuby on Rails application?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ruby comes with a built in logging library, but there's [log4r](http://web.archive.org/web/20090908004940/http://log4r.sourceforge.net).

A short example of the built in library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'logger'

log = Logger.new('mylog.txt')
log.debug "Hello log"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now [lenny/log4jruby](https://github.com/lenny/log4jruby) if anyone is here closer to 2020